# Why my kafka connects to mysql8.0 always encounters problem?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mysql-8.0

When I try to connect to mysql8.0 with kafka connect,there are always a problem about my driver.
The problem is no suitable driver for found

This is for a new CentOS7
plugin.path = [share/java, /root/confluent-5.2.1/share/confluent-hub-components]
Under the directory of /root/confluent-5.2.1/share/confluent-hub-components,
there are tow drivers:

```py
[root@localhost confluent-hub-components]# ls
confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc  debezium-debezium-connector-mysql
```

My driver is

```py
[root@localhost confluent-hub-components]# cd confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc/
[root@localhost confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc]# ls
assets  doc  etc  lib  manifest.json
[root@localhost confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc]# cd lib
[root@localhost lib]# ls
audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar  jline-0.9.94.jar  kafka-connect-jdbc-5.2.1.jar  postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc41.jar  sqlite-jdbc-3.25.2.jar  zookeeper-3.4.13.jar
common-utils-5.2.1.jar          jtds-1.3.1.jar    netty-3.10.6.Final.jar        slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar            zkclient-0.10.jar
```

Here is my code

```py
 bin/connect-standalone etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/mysql-source.properties
```

mysql-source.properties:

```py
#tasks to create:
name=jdbc-source-mysql-01
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
#tasks.max=1
# a table called 'users' will be written to the topic 'test-mysql-jdbc-users'.
connection.user=root
connection.password=root
connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employees
mode=bulk
#incrementing.column.name=fdsid
topic.prefix=test-mysql-jdbc-
```

Error:

```
Invalid value java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employees for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employees
```

Comment: I don't see a mysql jdbc driver in your lib directory. There is one for postgreSQL and others, but I am missing `mysql-connector-java.jar`

Comment: ```kafka-connect-jdbc-5.2.1.jar``` can't play the part of ```mysql-connector-java.jar```?

Comment: No, I don't think so. The JDBC drivers are created by the database vendors. The way they communicate with the database is proprietary stuff. No one will be going to re-implement an existing lib. I am not a kafka / confluent expert. But the missing jar file and the error message of a missing driver point in that direction. Have you tried adding mysql-connector-jdbc to the lib-directory?

Comment: I try to move ```mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar``` to the directory of   ```[root@localhost confluent-hub-components]```.But it doesn't work

Comment: I can only give you a link to a reference documentation: https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-connector/index.html  - There is a section about Configuration / JDBC drivers. Maybe it helps.

Comment: I think My connection.url is wrong, but I edit it many times. It is always the problem

Comment: ok,thank you. Maybe Useful

Comment: I find the clue ```SQLite is installed. You can also use another database. If you are using another database, be sure to adjust the connection.url setting. Confluent Platform includes JDBC drivers for SQLite and PostgreSQL, but if you're using a different database you must also verify that the JDBC driver is available on the Kafka Connect process's CLASSPATH```. I put the path of mysql drivers.jar in the /etc/profile. And it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MySQL driver **does not ship** with the Kafka Connect JDBC connector. You have to install it yourself and in the correct location.

You need to put the relevant MySQL JDBC Driver JAR in the Kafka Connect JDBC folder *before you start the Kafka Connect worker*

[This post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector#jdbc-drivers) will help you out with more detail.

Comment: Yeah,I have read your articles. But I didn't notice it. It's helpful.Thank you

Comment: Great. Feel free to mark the question as answered if this is correct :)